# Draw lines between connected nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemscontrol

**Overview**: I have a XAML Canvas control onto which I have placed several Line controls. The lines appear where they should not, and my conclusion is that the bounding boxes of said lines are misbehaving. I do not access or alter these bounding boxes (as far as I know).

**Project details**: I'm using WPF, XAML, C# and the MVVM pattern, all within Visual Studio 2010.

**More detailed explanation**: My project is to create a canvas and have items on that canvas that can be dragged around by the user. Lines are drawn between one item and another, to show a visual link.

To visualise, you can see an image here:

[image]

There are five items and in the code the N1 item should be linked by lines to the N3, N4 and N5 items. The N1 to N3 line seems to be fine, but the other two are offset. If you were to move them up, they would link the items together nicely.

The first thing you might consider is the co-ordinates of the lines within the Canvas, and I have done this.

Please view this image:

[image]

I added a TextBlock to the XAML within the same region as the Line and bound its Text to the StartingPoint of the Line. It might be difficult to see here if the image is small, but I can tell you that the StartingPont is the same for both lines here. And yet, clearly we can see that the lines are not in the same place.

I also thought that this could be a problem of alignment. I do not set any alignments within my project so I thought maybe this was the problem. I changed my lines to have different alignments (horizontal and vertical) as well as the items themselves, and I observed no difference.

**Project in more detail:**

First is the resource for the item itself. I don't imagine it makes a difference, but since I am all out of ideas, I can't discount that the problem might be somewhere unseen:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightBlue" Margin="2" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NodeText}" Background="Aqua"/>
                </StackPanel>
                </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Now there is, below that, the Canvas itself with the ItemsControls within:

```
<Canvas>


    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NodeList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LineList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <StackPanel>
                                <Line Stroke="Black" X1="{Binding StartPoint.X}" Y1="{Binding StartPoint.Y}" X2="{Binding EndPoint.X}" Y2="{Binding EndPoint.Y}"  />
                            <!--Path Stroke="Black" Data="{Binding}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" StrokeMiterLimit="1"/-->
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartPoint}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>


    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NodeList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding CanvasLeft}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding CanvasTop}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Thumb Name="myThumb" Template="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragDelta">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DragDeltaCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Thumb>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

I do have two sections here; two separate ItemsControls which have slightly different purposes. I assume this is okay, although assumptions may be how I ended up with this problem in the first instance.

Now the next part is some of the code behind and, I think, the main part is the OnDragDelta; the event handler for dragging the item around the Canvas:

```
void OnDeltaDrag(DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        CanvasLeft += e.HorizontalChange;
        CanvasTop += e.VerticalChange;

        UpdateLines();
    }
```

And then, of course, 'UpdateLines':

```
public void UpdateLines()
    {
        // Assess next nodes. Their lines will need to be changed - their start points will have to move with this node.
        for (int i = 0; i < this.NextNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            this.LineList.ElementAt(i).StartPoint = new Point(this.CanvasLeft, this.CanvasTop);
        }

        // Assess previous nodes. If they have lines to this node, the end points of those
        // lines will need to be moved (more specifically, moved to have the same coords as this).
        foreach (NodeViewModel n in this.PreviousNodes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n.NextNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (n.NextNodes.ElementAt(i) == this)
                {
                    n.LineList.ElementAt(i).EndPoint = new Point(this.CanvasLeft, this.CanvasTop);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, if you already have a LineGeometry, it may make sense to use a Path control (instead of a Line) and bind its Data property, i.e. `<Path Stroke="Black" Data="{Binding}"/>`

Comment: Your view-models contain `LineGeometry` objects, am I right? It is absolutely wrong for MVVM. Also there should not be properties like `CanvasLeft` and `CanvasTop` in a view-model. View-model must never know about view. You can use `X` and `Y` properties instead. Also it is bad to hold reference on the parent list in nodes. You should review architecture of your app.

Comment: CanvasLeft and CanvasTop are just the names of two doubles within NodeViewModel. I could call them X and Y, but I don't really understand what that would change. If I don't have two such values in a node, how can I bind the position? And yes, the architecture might well be wrong, but I'm not sure how to access a method within the Node List class from the node without a reference to it. I'm happy to hear suggestions.

Comment: @TheFaithfulLearner I use two approaches in such cases: **1)** raise event in child view-model and subscribe to it in parent **2)** pass reference on parent by some interface that contains only what your child view-model needs from parent one. If type of `ParentList` property is `NodeListViewModel` that it is a bad practice since child class knows more than it really needs. Disadvantage of using `CanvasLeft` that your view-model does guessing about where it will be used in view.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to your question. Post them as an answer. Also you don't need to point people to the answer, they will find it themselves. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@xum59 already mentioned [the default ItemsPanel for an ItemsControl is a StackPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0),
which is causing the stacking behaviour. The overall implementation of your solution looks awkward, however, I prepared a `WpfApp` (using MVVM Light) to show one way of handling this more gracefully.

- A `Node` class holding only data, implementing a clear separation with the (geometry) types belonging in the view
- A `NodeToPathDataConverter` in charge of redrawing the connecting lines, each time the `NodeList` `PropertyChanged` event is raised.
- A `DragDeltaCommand` updates the `Node` data behind the `Thumb` being dragged, after which `NodeList` `PropertyChanged` event is raised.
- As all lines are redrawn on every drag, I've chosen to go with the lightweight `StreamGeometry`.

**Node.cs**

```
public class Node : ObservableObject
{
    private double x;
    public double X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { Set(() => X, ref x, value); }
    }

    private double y;
    public double Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { Set(() => Y, ref y, value); }
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<string> NextNodes { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Node> GetSampleNodes()
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Node>()
        {
            new Node { X = 300, Y = 100, Text = "n1", NextNodes = new List<string> { "n2", "n4", "n5" } },
            new Node { X = 150, Y = 200, Text = "n2", NextNodes = new List<string> { "n3" } },
            new Node { X =  50, Y = 450, Text = "n3" },
            new Node { X = 200, Y = 500, Text = "n4" },
            new Node { X = 700, Y = 500, Text = "n5" }
        };
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:NodeToPathDataConverter x:Key="NodeToPathDataConverter" />
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightBlue" Margin="2" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" Background="AntiqueWhite" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Background="Aqua" TextAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MainViewModel.NodeList, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Path Stroke="Black">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NodeToPathDataConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="MainViewModel.NodeList" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />
                                    <Binding />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                        <Thumb Template="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragDelta">
                                    <cmd:EventToCommand 
                                        Command="{Binding MainViewModel.DragDeltaCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Thumb>
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns Geometry of line(s) from current node to next node(s)
/// </summary>
public class NodeToPathDataConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var nodes = values[0] as ObservableCollection<Node>;
        Node node = values[1] as Node;
        if (nodes != null && node != null && node.NextNodes != null)
        {
            // Create a StreamGeometry to draw line(s) from the current to the next node(s).
            StreamGeometry geometry = new StreamGeometry();
            using (StreamGeometryContext ctx = geometry.Open())
            {
                foreach (string nextText in node.NextNodes)
                {
                    Node nextNode = nodes.Single(n => n.Text == nextText);
                    ctx.BeginFigure(new Point(0, 0), false /* is filled */, false /* is closed */);
                    ctx.LineTo(new Point(nextNode.X - node.X, nextNode.Y - node.Y), true /* is stroked */, false /* is smooth join */);
                }
            }
            // Freeze the geometry (make it unmodifiable) for additional performance benefits.
            geometry.Freeze();
            return geometry;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Node> nodeList;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        nodeList = Node.GetSampleNodes();
        DragDeltaCommand = new RelayCommand<DragDeltaEventArgs>(e => OnDeltaDrag(e));
    }

    public ICommand DragDeltaCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Node> NodeList
    {
        get { return nodeList; }
    }

    private void OnDeltaDrag(DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Thumb thumb = e.Source as Thumb;
        if (thumb != null)
        {
            Node node = (Node)thumb.DataContext;
            node.X += e.HorizontalChange;
            node.Y += e.VerticalChange;

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => NodeList);
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Situation at startup*

[image: startup]

---

*After dragging node n1*

[image: dragged]

Comment: Hey man. This is a stellar answer and you're the man on this one. I'd like to ask a couple newbie-ish questions if I may so I might understand better the answer.
1: you use a lot the StaticResource 'Locator'. Is that not a name you're supposed to define somewhere? I don't see it anywhere.
2: This multibinding thing... in the converter what are you expecting to get in 'values'? Element 0 is an ObservableCollection of Nodes and element 1 is a Node? This bit confuses me.
3. I've not seen this notation before: set { Set(() => X, ref x, value); } - can I ask what benefits this way confers?

Comment: Sorry, ran out of characters. So yeah, #3 was the setter I've not seen before and #4 (the last one) is about the expression in the RaisePropertyChanged. Is RaisePropertyChanged(() => NodeList) the equivalent of RaisePropertyChanged("NodeList");? If not, what benefit does this method confer?
Thanks again for your help so far, it's a great job and I truly appreciate the effort and time.

Comment: You're welcome @TheFaithfulLearner. The `MultiBinding` takes the `NodeList` and the current `Node` respectively. All your other questions boil down to uses of the MVVM Light toolkit. [Here](http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-toolkit-example)'s 
a good tutorial to get you sorted. Also, on the overloaded methods, ref [their strengths and weaknesses](http://blog.amusedia.com/2013/06/inotifypropertychanged-implementation.html).

Comment: Alright man. I mean, you've done more than I could ask for so you get that sweet bounty.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have draggable nodes linked to some other nodes, you could do much more simple.

First, coordinates are relative to a parent. You should ensure that every drawing uses the same parent control, or gets pushed to the right place using a `RenderTransform` for example.

Second, the `<ItemsControl>` default panel is always a `<StackPanel>`, even if its parent is a `<Canvas>`. Because of this, your first template stacks the lines of each node in different `ContentControl` as in a `ListView`, each one having its own origin.

I'd rather build my Node model using 2 coordinates (CanvasLeft and CanvasTop) and a list (say `ObservableCollection`) of related nodes.

Then you'll have to draw a line from your node to each related node.

More or less, you should end up with something like :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NodeList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <Canvas/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <!--using Canvas to avoid stacking of node template and ItemsControl for lines-->
      <Canvas>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedNodes}" 
                      Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=CanvasTop}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=CanvasLeft}">
        <!--every line will have to be drawn from the current node-->
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <!--draw a line from the center of the node (0,0) to the center of the related (CanvasTop_of_the_related - CanvasTop_of_the_current)-->
              <Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="{Binding RelativeCanvasLeft}" Y2="{Binding RelativeCanvasTop}" />
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <!--drawing the node on top of the lines-->
        <!--use a RenderTransform if needed to "center" on (0,0)-->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"/>
      </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

There must be some way to avoid the precalculation of relative coordinates to rely on a simple binding or a converter.

Comment: Thank you, although I wish to ask a few questions to clarify the details. So I create a canvas that is aligned with the node, and that is where you set Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left in the ItemsControl?
Also, the relative canvas left and relative canvas top are a coordinate for the joined node, but assuming that the original node will always be at (0,0)?

Comment: For every node, the template defines a new `Canvas` that is moved into the node position. In the template, the node is placed at (0,0) because the `Canvas` is in the right place. For the relative coordinates of related nodes, you'll have to calculate the difference between their CanvasTop and CanvasLeft respective values.

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of the ContentControl is here? I don't have anything of that nature - what do you anticipate for this StaticResource to be?

Comment: In fact... can we go back a step? Is this XAML intended to replace BOTH the ItemsControls that I use? I have the one that draws the lines and the one that contains the Thumb for dragging. I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that it replaces only the one for the lines. But the one with the Thumb has this line:
    <Thumb Name="myThumb" Template="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}">
And that requires a Control Template. The one you're suggesting requires a Data Template. NodeTemplate can only be one of the other, so therefore I'm a little confused.

Comment: Right, I used only one ItemsControl to replace the 2 you proposed. I recognize I've oversimplified your DataTemplate of the second ItemsControl. I assumed you asked for explanations on why Lines were drawn on top of each other and how to get them in place... I think my answer contains both of these, Let me know...

Comment: Yeah, that's okay. I've got that part sorted. The problem I'm having is that all the nodes are being drawn in the same place. I haven't changed their initialisation values. I've put a break point in the getter of CanvasTop and CanvasLeft - they are being retrieved and the values are the ones I gave them. That is, they're all different.

Comment: So they should all be in different places, but they're not. And they're not at the top left of the window either. If I remove nodes from NodeList, this position doesn't change, and changing the coordinates I have for these items does nothing.